# Oracle OCI parallel connection to an encrypted and non-encrypted Oracle instance

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

From the same PHP script I need to connect to two different Oracle databases, one which requires an encrypted connection and one which doesn't. The problem is that the one which requires encrypted connection doesn't mandate it on servers side, so I need to set 'require' on client side.

I can do that by creating an sqlnet.ora file in my $ORACLE_HOME:

> SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_CLIENT = (MD5)
>   SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT = (RC4_256)
>   SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT = required
>   SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_CLIENT = required

The problem is that then my other connection will also require encryption, so it will fail.
I need both connections in the same script, so I cannot just set a different ORACLE_HOME for the two, as they are part of the same script.

Anybody has any idea how to resolve this?
Would it be possible to set the encryption on connection level, so I could set one as 'require' and other to 'none'?
Would it be possible to have two different ORACLE_HOMEs in the same script for the two different connections?

Comment: Luckily it turns out that the server side was set to mandate the encryption, so I don't need to force the encryption from my side, so I can connect to both the encrypted and non-encrypted instance from the same script. But the question is still valid, I don't see how could I force and encryption for one and not for another database from the client from the same script if that would ever come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **required** the connection will fail if the other side specifies rejected (no encryption), or if there is no compatible algorithm on the other side.

You need to use **requested**. When using requested the service (encryption) will be active if the other side of the connection specifies either accepted, required, or requested, and there is a compatible algorithm available on the other side; it will otherwise be inactive (but wont fail).

Source: [Oracle Database Online Documentation 11g Release 1 (11.1) / Database Administration / Securing the Network](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_network_secure.htm)